# Generic Entity Framework and DTO repository where lambda issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, lambda

Im trying to implement a layered application using entity framework, and DTO's to pass objects between layers.

I have been following through some code on line to set up a generic respository but I have run in to a couple of methods I cant solve.

Im using EntitiesToDTOs to generate my DTO's from the edmx file, but unfortunately they dont have a base class (there are too many to update manually)

To Set the scene I have the following 2 generic classes:

**IRepository:**

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new empty entity.
    /// </summary>
    TEntity Create();

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the existing entity.
    /// </summary>
    TEntity Create(TEntity entity);

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the existing entity.
    /// </summary>
    TEntity Update(TEntity entity);

    /// <summary>
    /// Delete an entity using its primary key.
    /// </summary>
    void Delete(long id);

    /// <summary>
    /// Delete the given entity.
    /// </summary>
    void Delete(TEntity entity);

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes the existing entity.
    /// </summary>
    void Delete(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where);

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds one entity based on provided criteria.
    /// </summary>
    TEntity FindOne(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where = null);

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds one entity based on its Identifier.
    /// </summary>
    TEntity FindById(long id);

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds entities based on provided criteria.
    /// </summary>
    IQueryable<TEntity> FindAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where = null);

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds other related entities based of type T for queries.
    /// </summary>
    IQueryable<T> Set<T>() where T : class;

    /// <summary>
    /// Save any changes to the TContext
    /// </summary>
    bool SaveChanges();
}
```

**Generic Implementation:**

```
public class Repository<TEntity, TContext> : IRepository<TEntity>, IDisposable
      where TEntity : class
      where TContext : DbContext
{
    protected TContext Context;

    public Repository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        Context = dbContext as TContext;
    }

    public virtual TEntity Create()
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().Create();
    }

    public virtual TEntity Create(TEntity entity)
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual TEntity Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        return entity;
    }

    public virtual void Delete(long id)
    {
        var item = Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
        Context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(item);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        Context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
    {
        var objects = Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(where).AsEnumerable();
        foreach (var item in objects)
        {
            Context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(item);
        }
    }

    public virtual TEntity FindById(long id)
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }

    public virtual TEntity FindOne(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where = null)
    {
        return FindAll(where).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Set<T>() where T : class
    {
        return Context.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> FindAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where = null)
    {
        return null != where ? Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(where) : Context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual bool SaveChanges()
    {
        return 0 < Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Releases all resources used by the Entities
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (null != Context)
        {
            Context.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**The class used to convert between and Order record and an Order DTO:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Assembler for <see cref="Order"/> and <see cref="OrderDTO"/>.
/// </summary>
public static partial class OrderAssembler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when <see cref="ToDTO"/> operation is about to return.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dto"><see cref="OrderDTO"/> converted from <see cref="Order"/>.</param>
    static partial void OnDTO(this Order entity, OrderDTO dto);

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when <see cref="ToEntity"/> operation is about to return.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity"><see cref="Order"/> converted from <see cref="OrderDTO"/>.</param>
    static partial void OnEntity(this OrderDTO dto, Order entity);

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts this instance of <see cref="OrderDTO"/> to an instance of <see cref="Order"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dto"><see cref="OrderDTO"/> to convert.</param>
    public static Order ToEntity(this OrderDTO dto)
    {
        if (dto == null) return null;

        var entity = new Order();

        entity.OrderID = dto.OrderID;
        entity.SupplierID = dto.SupplierID;
        entity.Special = dto.Special;
        entity.RequestedBy = dto.RequestedBy;
        entity.RequestedFor = dto.RequestedFor;
        entity.Urgent = dto.Urgent;
        entity.OrderStatus = dto.OrderStatus;
        entity.DeliveryAddressID = dto.DeliveryAddressID;
        entity.OrderDate = dto.OrderDate;
        entity.Deleted = dto.Deleted;
        entity.SentToSage = dto.SentToSage;
        entity.Cancelled = dto.Cancelled;
        entity.InvoiceAddressID = dto.InvoiceAddressID;
        entity.SageOrderID = dto.SageOrderID;
        entity.SageDatabaseID = dto.SageDatabaseID;
        entity.DeliveryDate = dto.DeliveryDate;
        entity.SupplierReference = dto.SupplierReference;
        entity.Analysis1 = dto.Analysis1;
        entity.Analysis2 = dto.Analysis2;
        entity.Analysis3 = dto.Analysis3;
        entity.Analysis4 = dto.Analysis4;
        entity.Analysis5 = dto.Analysis5;
        entity.Analysis6 = dto.Analysis6;
        entity.OrderDiscount = dto.OrderDiscount;
        entity.SageDatabaseName = dto.SageDatabaseName;
        entity.SupplierName = dto.SupplierName;
        entity.RequestedByName = dto.RequestedByName;
        entity.DeliveryAddressName = dto.DeliveryAddressName;
        entity.NetValue = dto.NetValue;
        entity.DepartmentID = dto.DepartmentID;
        entity.PODocumentNo = dto.PODocumentNo;
        entity.ConstructRelated = dto.ConstructRelated;
        entity.Archived = dto.Archived;
        entity.UpdateStatus = dto.UpdateStatus;
        entity.UpdatedDate = dto.UpdatedDate;
        entity.UpdatedUser = dto.UpdatedUser;
        entity.WarehouseID = dto.WarehouseID;
        entity.ExchangeRate = dto.ExchangeRate;
        entity.CurrencySymbol = dto.CurrencySymbol;
        entity.SupplierEmailAddress = dto.SupplierEmailAddress;
        entity.SupplierContactName = dto.SupplierContactName;
        entity.SupplierTelephone = dto.SupplierTelephone;
        entity.SupplierFax = dto.SupplierFax;
        entity.HasAttachments = dto.HasAttachments;
        entity.HasAnalysisValues = dto.HasAnalysisValues;
        entity.SYSTraderAnalysisValueID = dto.SYSTraderAnalysisValueID;
        entity.InternalOrder = dto.InternalOrder;
        entity.DeliveryPostalName = dto.DeliveryPostalName;
        entity.DeliveryAddressLine1 = dto.DeliveryAddressLine1;
        entity.DeliveryAddressLine2 = dto.DeliveryAddressLine2;
        entity.DeliveryAddressLine3 = dto.DeliveryAddressLine3;
        entity.DeliveryAddressLine4 = dto.DeliveryAddressLine4;
        entity.DeliveryPostCode = dto.DeliveryPostCode;
        entity.InvoicePostalName = dto.InvoicePostalName;
        entity.InvoiceAddressLine1 = dto.InvoiceAddressLine1;
        entity.InvoiceAddressLine2 = dto.InvoiceAddressLine2;
        entity.InvoiceAddressLine3 = dto.InvoiceAddressLine3;
        entity.InvoiceAddressLine4 = dto.InvoiceAddressLine4;
        entity.InvoicePostCode = dto.InvoicePostCode;
        entity.DeliveryContactName = dto.DeliveryContactName;
        entity.InvoiceContactName = dto.InvoiceContactName;
        entity.DeliveryTelephoneNo = dto.DeliveryTelephoneNo;
        entity.DeliveryFaxNo = dto.DeliveryFaxNo;
        entity.InvoiceTelephoneNo = dto.InvoiceTelephoneNo;
        entity.InvoiceFaxNo = dto.InvoiceFaxNo;
        entity.CheckForNewDocuments = dto.CheckForNewDocuments;
        entity.EmailSent = dto.EmailSent;
        entity.DocumentNoPrefix = dto.DocumentNoPrefix;

        dto.OnEntity(entity);

        return entity;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts this instance of <see cref="Order"/> to an instance of <see cref="OrderDTO"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity"><see cref="Order"/> to convert.</param>
    public static OrderDTO ToDTO(this Order entity)
    {
        if (entity == null) return null;

        var dto = new OrderDTO();

        dto.OrderID = entity.OrderID;
        dto.SupplierID = entity.SupplierID;
        dto.Special = entity.Special;
        dto.RequestedBy = entity.RequestedBy;
        dto.RequestedFor = entity.RequestedFor;
        dto.Urgent = entity.Urgent;
        dto.OrderStatus = entity.OrderStatus;
        dto.DeliveryAddressID = entity.DeliveryAddressID;
        dto.OrderDate = entity.OrderDate;
        dto.Deleted = entity.Deleted;
        dto.SentToSage = entity.SentToSage;
        dto.Cancelled = entity.Cancelled;
        dto.InvoiceAddressID = entity.InvoiceAddressID;
        dto.SageOrderID = entity.SageOrderID;
        dto.SageDatabaseID = entity.SageDatabaseID;
        dto.DeliveryDate = entity.DeliveryDate;
        dto.SupplierReference = entity.SupplierReference;
        dto.Analysis1 = entity.Analysis1;
        dto.Analysis2 = entity.Analysis2;
        dto.Analysis3 = entity.Analysis3;
        dto.Analysis4 = entity.Analysis4;
        dto.Analysis5 = entity.Analysis5;
        dto.Analysis6 = entity.Analysis6;
        dto.OrderDiscount = entity.OrderDiscount;
        dto.SageDatabaseName = entity.SageDatabaseName;
        dto.SupplierName = entity.SupplierName;
        dto.RequestedByName = entity.RequestedByName;
        dto.DeliveryAddressName = entity.DeliveryAddressName;
        dto.NetValue = entity.NetValue;
        dto.DepartmentID = entity.DepartmentID;
        dto.PODocumentNo = entity.PODocumentNo;
        dto.ConstructRelated = entity.ConstructRelated;
        dto.Archived = entity.Archived;
        dto.UpdateStatus = entity.UpdateStatus;
        dto.UpdatedDate = entity.UpdatedDate;
        dto.UpdatedUser = entity.UpdatedUser;
        dto.WarehouseID = entity.WarehouseID;
        dto.ExchangeRate = entity.ExchangeRate;
        dto.CurrencySymbol = entity.CurrencySymbol;
        dto.SupplierEmailAddress = entity.SupplierEmailAddress;
        dto.SupplierContactName = entity.SupplierContactName;
        dto.SupplierTelephone = entity.SupplierTelephone;
        dto.SupplierFax = entity.SupplierFax;
        dto.HasAttachments = entity.HasAttachments;
        dto.HasAnalysisValues = entity.HasAnalysisValues;
        dto.SYSTraderAnalysisValueID = entity.SYSTraderAnalysisValueID;
        dto.InternalOrder = entity.InternalOrder;
        dto.DeliveryPostalName = entity.DeliveryPostalName;
        dto.DeliveryAddressLine1 = entity.DeliveryAddressLine1;
        dto.DeliveryAddressLine2 = entity.DeliveryAddressLine2;
        dto.DeliveryAddressLine3 = entity.DeliveryAddressLine3;
        dto.DeliveryAddressLine4 = entity.DeliveryAddressLine4;
        dto.DeliveryPostCode = entity.DeliveryPostCode;
        dto.InvoicePostalName = entity.InvoicePostalName;
        dto.InvoiceAddressLine1 = entity.InvoiceAddressLine1;
        dto.InvoiceAddressLine2 = entity.InvoiceAddressLine2;
        dto.InvoiceAddressLine3 = entity.InvoiceAddressLine3;
        dto.InvoiceAddressLine4 = entity.InvoiceAddressLine4;
        dto.InvoicePostCode = entity.InvoicePostCode;
        dto.DeliveryContactName = entity.DeliveryContactName;
        dto.InvoiceContactName = entity.InvoiceContactName;
        dto.DeliveryTelephoneNo = entity.DeliveryTelephoneNo;
        dto.DeliveryFaxNo = entity.DeliveryFaxNo;
        dto.InvoiceTelephoneNo = entity.InvoiceTelephoneNo;
        dto.InvoiceFaxNo = entity.InvoiceFaxNo;
        dto.CheckForNewDocuments = entity.CheckForNewDocuments;
        dto.EmailSent = entity.EmailSent;
        dto.DocumentNoPrefix = entity.DocumentNoPrefix;

        entity.OnDTO(dto);

        return dto;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts each instance of <see cref="OrderDTO"/> to an instance of <see cref="Order"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dtos"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<Order> ToEntities(this IEnumerable<OrderDTO> dtos)
    {
        if (dtos == null) return null;

        return dtos.Select(e => e.ToEntity()).ToList();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts each instance of <see cref="Order"/> to an instance of <see cref="OrderDTO"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entities"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<OrderDTO> ToDTOs(this IEnumerable<Order> entities)
    {
        if (entities == null) return null;

        return entities.Select(e => e.ToDTO()).ToList();
    }
}
```

**My implementation of an 'OrderRepository':**

```
public class OrderRepository : IRepository<OrderDTO>
{
    private Repository<Order, WAPEntities> _repository;

    public OrderRepository()
    {
        _repository = new Repository<Order, WAPEntities>(new WAPEntities());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _repository.Dispose();
    }

    public OrderDTO Create()
    {
        return _repository.Create().ToDTO();
    }

    public OrderDTO Create(OrderDTO entity)
    {
        return _repository.Create(entity.ToEntity()).ToDTO();
    }

    public OrderDTO Update(OrderDTO entity)
    {
        return _repository.Update(entity.ToEntity()).ToDTO();
    }

    public void Delete(long id)
    {
        _repository.Delete(id);
    }

    public void Delete(OrderDTO entity)
    {
        _repository.Delete(entity.ToEntity());
    }

    public void Delete(Expression<Func<OrderDTO, bool>> where)
    {
        // I have tried this but it wont work
        var resultBody = Expression.Convert(where.Body, typeof(OrderDTO));
        var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<Order, bool>>(resultBody, where.Parameters);

        _repository.Delete(result);
    }

    public OrderDTO FindOne(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<OrderDTO, bool>> where = null)
    {
        //Here the same issue with the Where clause
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public OrderDTO FindById(long id)
    {
        return _repository.FindById(id).ToDTO();
    }

    public IQueryable<OrderDTO> FindAll(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<OrderDTO, bool>> where = null)
    {
        //Here the same issue with the Where clause
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Set<T>() where T : class
    {
        return _repository.Set<T>();
    }

    public bool SaveChanges()
    {
        return _repository.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

As you can see, for most of my Order Repository methods, I can convert from Entities to DTOs, and from DTOs to entities pretty easily.

The ones im struggling with is how to convert that lamda where clause to convert from a lambda that takes my Order DTO class, and calls entity.ToDTO() on it and converts to a lambda for the order entity.

The methods I cant work out are:

```
public void Delete(Expression<Func<OrderDTO, bool>> where)

public OrderDTO FindOne(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<OrderDTO, bool>> where = null)

public IQueryable<OrderDTO> FindAll(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<OrderDTO, bool>> where = null)
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Are you aware of AutoMapper ? It's very good and maybe it would help a lot. This is not directly related with your question though

Comment: I came across it today when reading about EF, I found it after I found the EntiesToDTos extension for visual studio. I saw a few comments saying it can be an issue with EF so it put me off a bit :/

Comment: I am using it with E.F 4.5 and it works great ! You can map a class with only two lines of code. And the same also applies to a list of objects. It has very good functionalities.

Comment: Thanks ill check it out, still kind of in the R&D stage at the moment, trying to re-factor a larger product and trying to avoiding coding thousands of DTO classes!

Comment: just had a quick look at auto mapper and it looks like its doing the same thing as my order assembler class ( although its much prettier, however I think im still going to have the issue with how to covert those lambdas!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that you're trying to treat your DTO's as if they were entities.  They're not.

Entities are Entities.. They're the objects that are mapped in your data context.  DTO's are just simple, dumb objects used to transfer data, as their name suggests.  If your DTO's were exactly the same as your Entities, there would be no reason to have them both.

When it comes to your lambda's.. you're talking two different things.  A lambda expression against a DTO is not the same as a lambda expression against an entity.  While you can modify an expression tree, it's not fun and is a lot of work.

I have to question why you are introducing this extra abstraction if all you're going to do is treat it exactly like you would your entities.  If your abstraction provides no value, I would avoid it... unless you expect that you will be changing database technology later.. in which case maybe it has some benefit.. but even if that's the case you're still treating your DTO's as if they're EF objects, which means doing a logical translation to whatever new technology you're using.

You should think about the scenarios you intend to use the lambda for.  I'm guessing most likely it's to deal with collections of objects.  In which case, why not just make a functions that take a collection of DTO's and then translate that to your Lambda.. that would be a lot easier.

The real benefit of this is that if you change your data model, you only have to change your repository.  When you start using lambdas all over in your code, every time you change something you have to go find everywhere you're using that lambda.  It's highly beneficial to centralize your lambda code.

Comment: Take a collection and covert it to a lambda? I am scratching my head on what could you possibly meant.

Comment: @WiktorZychla - I mean use an expression to perform the action on the items based on the contents of the collection, such as using a Contains. `repository.Delete(x => itemsToDelete.Contains(x.Id))` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps I am just making work for myself here, I also had a thought last night, I could just expose the DB set in a protected property, then i could write direct linq queries over it when needed

Comment: @WraithNath - If you're going to do that, then you are effectively nullifying the purpose of your repository.  You should either enforce the separation, or get rid of it all together.

Comment: @MystereMan - thanks, I have decided to get rid of it, now the objects from the data layer are used throughout the other layers, this has also enabled me to use the generic repositories as is.